# Spring Boot with Azure Application Insights Enabled Starts with Error -read Only File system

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

Spring boot application running in Linux Azure App Service (Java SE) starts with below warning if Application Insights is enabled. Application Insights doesn't show any data related tot the application.

> Running STARTUP_COMMAND: java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=test
> /home/site/wwwroot/app.jar -Dserver.port=80
> -Duser.dir=/local/site/wwwroot

Following line is printed in the logs.

> m.applicationinsights.agent - Detected running on a read-only file
> system. Status json file won't be created. If this is unexpected,
> please check that process has write access to the directory:
> /root/LogFiles/ApplicationInsights/status

Does this file permission error causes no telemetry data being send to Application Insights? No other error found in the application logs.

Answer (score 0):

In an App Service, the only directory where you can write is in /home/site

The destination directory should be /home/site/wwwroot

Comment: This path is default taken by Azure Application Insights spring noor starter. Any idea how to change it ?